# Sending sms when device shutting down

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to make a broadcast receiver that sends a simple sms to some phone number when the device is shutting down.

Here is my code:

```
public class ShutDownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("Log","Device shutting down NOW!");

                        //An actual phone number here
    sms.sendTextMessage("0670#######", null, "This is a text for sms", null, null);

       }
```

}

So far the results:

I can clearly see the log message when i turn off the device.
So the BroadcastReceiver working well on shut down, but NO sms sending, NO Exceptions.

I tryed this sms sending method with a simple button click, with absolute success.

So, i know that the sms sending method is correct, i know that the shutdown receiver is correct, BUT for some reason it is not sending the sms.

Any ideas about this?
(I work with real devices, not emulators.)

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same it is not possible because related system services have been disabled. If anyone able to achieve this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ....

```
SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, smsText, null, null);
```

... and that works pretty well as long as

1. the phone number is valid
2. the message text isn't too long
3. the telephony service is available (have you tried another event to ensure that the service isn't closed before you receive the shutdown?)
4. `android.permission.SEND_SMS` is granted

Hope this helps ... cheers!

Comment: err.. What do you mean by number 3? I can send the sms elsewhere, but cannot send at shutdown.. I still got the log message about "shutting down".

Comment: What I was thinking of, is: when your device is shutting down - could it be that at the point of time the ShutdownReceiver fires you can't send messages anymore because related system services have been disabled? Well, I have no idea ... that was just a guess

Comment: Yea this is the first thing i could imagine too, it would be nice if someone could point me straight to this.